# Ember data create record and add incrementProperty/decrementProperty on additional clicks

Tags: javascript, ember.js, local-storage, ember-data

I am trying to create a cart type order page in emberjs.

This is what it looks like http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qanujodo/3#/tickets

When clicked on add one ticket the model that saves is for that ticketQuantity, and when added one more it also adds the model by duplicating the model records.

What I want to do is, when the ticketQuantity changes it will update the data store record and if the same ticketType record is present it will remove those records and save the current record based on the ticketQuantity .

Currently when I add one it does adds the record into the data store, and if added more then the record is stored but the previous records are not deleted. It should be true for all the ticketTypes.

Ideally it should be as pointed out by rwjblue in #emberjs irc, ticketController should keep track of the order it creates and only create once, then just incrementProperty/decrementProperty as needed on subsequent cliks on add one/decrease one button. 
How do I go about this ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out: http://jsbin.com/giticexa/3#/tickets

Didn't touch the UI, but you can see the model either created if not present or increment existing model if one matches.

Best of luck!